# How to calculate ODS, OIS and AP metrics?

Tags: image, processing, metrics, detection

I'm working on image edge detection and i need to calculate optimal dataset scale (ODS), optimal image scale (OIS) and average precision (AP) metrics? Is there any example for python or matlab? Or how to calculate this metrics? Thanks for help.

I didn't find any example or formula.